# kony : rm failed for -f, No such file or directory while try to emulate on android device

Tags: emulation, temenos-quantum

When i try  to  emulate on android device, I am getting the below error 
rm failed for -f, No such file or directory

```
I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.acti
on.MAIN categories={android.intent.category.HOME} flags=0x10000000 comp={com.and
roid.sdksetup/com.android.sdksetup.DefaultActivity} }
Uninstalling kony application

Failure
rm failed for /sdcard/profiler_com.orgname.TestApp1.txt, No such file or directo
ry
Installing kony application
1343 KB/s (2887184 bytes in 2.098s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/luavmandroid.apk
Failure [-12]
rm failed for -f, No such file or directory
Starting kony application
Starting: Intent { action=android.intent.action.MAIN comp={com.orgname.TestApp1/
com.orgname.TestApp1.TestApp1} }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.orgname.TestApp1/com.orgname.TestApp1.TestApp1} does
not exist.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Anybody has any idea regarding this ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "T3" emulator, you have to edit its configuration to use less memory and to use Google Api 16.

At least that fixed it for me.

You should check the [User's Guide](http://developer.kony.com/twiki/pub/Portal/Docs/Kony_Studio_User_Guide.pdf) to configure the emulator.